# TypeORM - Update only values that are provided and leave the rest as they are

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

How would I approach this using TypeORM?

I have an Entity lets call it EntityA.

I have 1 EntityA in my database with name = Joe, age = 17

Now my front end sends a post request to my API with an Object like { name: Joe, age: 16 }

How can I tell type orm to update the EntityA in the database with the name of "Joe" and only update the provided values that differ from what is currently stored in the database (age in this case) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had the same issue, especially with `undefined` values in `nullable` columns.
Take [my project's Product repository](https://github.com/GiovanniZotta/fog_cloud_project/blob/17bb3d77cbd5ce0987c61f934a68d23b46103a24/graphmarket/services/service-products/repositories/ProductRepository.ts) update function as a starting point.
I've used conditional [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (...) to "build" the query dynamically. See [this](https://www.sanity.io/blog/how-to-conditionally-build-an-object-in-es6) for more information.

```js
async function update(id: string, user: User): Promise<User> {
    // Update
    await userRepository.update(id, {
      ...(user.name && { name: user.name }),
      ...(user.surname && { surname: user.surname }),
      ...(user.age && { age: user.age }),
    });

    // Return
    return this.repository.findOneOrFail(id);
  }
```

Update only the columns that are present in `user`. E.g: If no `user.name` is present does not update it since it's not in the update object.

Comment: Great idea, but it still doesn't solve the original problem - if the user sends a user.name which is the same as in the DB, typeorm still updates it. You need to read the record from the DB, and add a comparison. Like: user.name && user.name !== currUser.name && ...

Comment: @Yehezkel No, too costly. If the values are the same, a single update is fine, since the records fields that are different are still updated.

Comment: I totally agree regarding the cost, just tried to answer the question exactly.